# Rails initializer for development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment, initializer

I have the following code in `/config/initializers/chargify.rb`

```
Chargify.configure do |c|
  c.subdomain = 'example'
  c.api_key   = '123xyz'
end
```

But I have different settings for development and production.

So, how would I have a different set of variables values based on environment?

Comment: Josh, is this what went into Baremetrics' MVP? History in the making right here :)

Comment: @JanKlimo Haha, naaa. This was over 3 years before Baremetrics was even an idea in my brain. :P

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would create a config file for this (`config/chargify.yml`):

```
development:
  subdomain: example
  api_key: 123abc
production:
  subdomain: production_domain
  api_key: 890xyz
```

And then change your Initializer like this:

```
chargify_config_file = File.join(Rails.root,'config','chargify.yml')
raise "#{chargify_config_file} is missing!" unless File.exists? chargify_config_file
chargify_config = YAML.load_file(chargify_config_file)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys

Chargify.configure do |c|
  c.subdomain = chargify_config[:subdomain]
  c.api_key   = chargify_config[:api_key]
end
```

Comment: Quick warning for anyone cutting and pasting from above: `sudomain: example` should be `subdomain: example`

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
Chargify.configure do |c|
  if Rails.env.production?
    # production settings
    c.api_key   = '123xyz'
  else
    # dev. and test settings
    c.api_key   = '123xyz'
  end
end
```

Better yet, you can reduce duplication with `case` block:

```
Chargify.configure do |c|
  c.subdomain = 'example'
  c.api_key   = case
    when Rails.env.production?
      '123xyz'
    when Rails.env.staging?
      'abc123'
    else
      'xyz123'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to need different settings for different environments, it's best to put them in the respective environment file, like `config/environments/development.rb`.

If you absolutely insist on putting them in an initializer (but please don't, that's what the environment files are for), you can use a `case` statement and inspect the value of `Rails.env`, which returns the name of the current environment as a string.

Comment: The comments in application.rb to *not* put configuration on those files and to put it in files in the initializers directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use env variables

```
Chargify.configure do |c|
  c.subdomain = ENV['APP_SUBDOMAIN']
  c.api_key = ENV['API_KEY']
end
```

and set appropriate variables in ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile
but note: this must be set for same user as Rails instance is opareting on. E.g. deploy user specified in capistrano is you used that for deployments